# How to get post category

Tags: wordpress

In home page I'm printing posts, and I want to print category name in foreach loop? How can I do that?

Sample code:

```
       if (have_posts()) : 

        $args = array(
            'showposts' => '5',
            'paged' => $paged
        );


        $thePosts = query_posts($args);

        foreach($thePosts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
<?php

            GLOBAL $wpdb;

            $query = "
            SELECT 
                terms.slug, r.term_taxonomy_id, terms.name AS cat_name 
            FROM 

                {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy t, {$wpdb->prefix}terms terms, $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->term_relationships r 

            WHERE 

                t.term_id=terms.term_id AND 
                p.ID = r.object_id AND
                r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id AND 
                p.ID = '".$post->ID."'

            ORDER BY terms.term_order ASC, terms.term_id DESC";

            $categories = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);


            if(is_array($categories)){

                $i=1;
                foreach($categories as $category) { 

                    echo '<span>'.$category['cat_name'].'</span>';

                    ++$i;
                }#end foreach($categories 

            }#end if


            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your loop.

```
<?php
/* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
$categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'twentyeleven' ) );

if ( '' != $categories_list ) {
$utility_text = __( 'This entry was posted in %1$s', 'twentyeleven' );
} 
printf( $utility_text );
?>
```

This will print the categories of current post. Hope you are using the child theme of twentyeleven.